# Прочитать MD5 Hash файла в консоли

Tags: c#, md5

Подскажите как реализовать проверку чтения файла на MD5 хеш сумму в консоли?

Есть метод для получения хеш суммы:

```
public static string ComputeMD5Checksum(string path)
{
   using (var FileOpen = File.OpenRead(path))
   using (var MdHash = new MD5CryptoServiceProvider())
   {
     return BitConverter.ToString(MdHash.ComputeHash(FileOpen)).Replace("-", string.Empty);
   }
}
```

Суть такова:
Открыть консольное окно, после перетащить .exe файл ( разный ) в консоль, посчитать из него хеш сумму и вывести на консоль.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

При перетаскивании в консоль информация о пути файла появиться в строке. После чего достаточно нажать Enter чтоб появился хэш.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        //Обработка файла перетянутого на Exe файл запуска
        if (args.Length > 0 && File.Exists(args[0]))
        {
            string filePath = args[0];
            Console.WriteLine(ComputeMD5Checksum(filePath));
        }

        //Обработка в бесконечном цикле файлов непосредственно перетянутых на открытую консоль
        while (true)
        {
            var filePath = Console.ReadLine();
            if (File.Exists(filePath))
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ComputeMD5Checksum(filePath));
            }
        }
    }

    public static string ComputeMD5Checksum(string path)
    {
        using (var FileOpen = File.OpenRead(path))
        using (var MdHash = new MD5CryptoServiceProvider())
        {
            return BitConverter.ToString(MdHash.ComputeHash(FileOpen)).Replace("-", string.Empty);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: У меня консоль сразу же закрывается, ставил `Console.ReadLine (Read)`

Comment: Нужно так, сначало открыл консоль, после переместил файл.

Comment: @Дмитрий: консоль находиться в постоянном цикле считывание и не должна закрываться до того как вы сами ее не закроете на крестик. И если она сразу закрывается значит в какой то момент вылетает Exception. Проверьте работу в построчном режиме (Debug).

Comment: Не доглядел =) Подскажите последнее, после того как я перетащил файл, мне показывает сначало путь того файла который я хочу считать, и только после нажатия "Enter" мне выводит информацию. Можно ли убрать путь и сразу считать информацию без нажатия на кнопку?

Comment: @Дмитрий: для этого вам придется написать костыль, который неплохо описан здесь) http://qaru.site/questions/53412/how-to-add-a-timeout-to-consolereadline

Comment: Честно говоря никогда не побывал реализовывать подобный функционал, а потому не могу гарантировать что решение предоставленное по указанной ссылке окажется хорошим.

Comment: Всё ровно спасибо большое.

Comment: @Дмитрий, пожалуйста)

Comment: @Дмитрий, и напоследок скажу что подобный функционал с перетягиванием довольно легко реализовывается без использования консоли простым обработчиком DragAndDrop например на WPF.